# Check and count intersection columns values between data frames

Tags: r

There are 2 data frames:

```
df_01:
id  n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6
1   1   2   3   4   5   6
2   6   5   4   3   2   1
... (2000000 rows)

df_02:
m1  m2  m3  m4  m5
1   2   3   4   5
5   4   3   2   1
... (1200 rows)
```

And I need to count now many values from a row of df_01 (`df_01[x, 2:7]`) are present for each row in df_02 (`df_02[x,]`) and store this value in somewhere. Something like this:

```
df_01:
id  n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6  df02.r1  df02.r2
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   5        2       #one column for each row from df_02
2   6   5   4   3   2   9   4        3
... (2000000 rows)

df_02:
m1  m2  m3  m4  m5
1   2   3   4   5
5   6   7   8   9
... (1200 rows)
```

Right now I'm using a `for` loop to iterate through rows from df_01 and a `while` loop to check intersection for each row from df_02, store count and appending to df_01.

Resumed code version:

```
rows <- nrow(df_02)
for (id in df_01$id) {
  df_01_row <- df_01[1,]
  new_row_count <- data.frame(r1 = 0)
  actual_row <- 1 # Actually, this value is computed (last row computed in df_02), df_02 will receive more rows and this function will be used to process update.
  while (actual_row <= rows) {
    new_row_count[, paste0("r", actual_row)] <- length(base::intersect(df_01_row[, 2:7], df_02[actual_row,]))
    # base::intersect running faster than dplyr::intersect in this case
    actual_row <- actual_row + 1
  }
  # append new_row_count to df_01 in database
}
```

This is a very long operation doing this way, and I'm using 2 computers, one for odds rows and another to evens rows from df_01 and a common DB (R mongolite) that store all computations. I'm using database because I need to store results for future reference and this will take days to complete.

I'm looking for something to do to make this more efficient (data schema change, packages, anything). Any advice are welcome.

Comment: Are there duplicates inside rows of "df1" or "df2"? How many unique values do both "df1" and "df2" have?

Comment: Are you really ready for that number of columns to be added to the original dataset? Machine resources would appear a significant concern. 2e6*1.2e3*10 bytes = 2.4e+10which I might get into my 32 GB machine but then I wouldn't be able to do anything with it.

Comment: @alexis_laz each row in df_01 and df_02 create a unique sequence in data frame.

Comment: @42- yes, it is my concern too, I'm not storing in memory after computation, only in database, after I can manage in database shell to create a new data set and use in R again. Right now in memory I have just 2 data frame and a couple of functions.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a possible solution using the purrr package.

I've added a custom function `counter()` to handle counting of values in a vector in each row of a data frame (slightly different approach to your use of `intersect()`).

`purrr::by_row()` is being used to do the rowwise iterations.

Can't say I'm sure how this will scale up to the number of rows you have to handle, but might be worth a shot!

Aside - I made minor adjustment to `df_01` to check results came out differently for each row (they seemed to be same before).

```
df_01 <- read.table(text="id  n1  n2  n3  n4  n5  n6
1   1   2   3   4   5   6
2   6   5   8   3   2   1", header=T)

df_02 <- read.table(text="m1  m2  m3  m4  m5
1   2   3   4   5
5   6   7   8   9", header=T)

library(purrr)
counter <- function(vals, df) {
  by_row(df, ~ sum(vals %in% .), .collate = "cols")$.out
}

x <- by_row(df_01[, -1], counter, df_02, .collate = "cols")
x
#>   n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6 .out1 .out2
#> 1  1  2  3  4  5  6     5     2
#> 2  6  5  8  3  2  1     4     3

# The rename columns
colnames(x) <- sub("\\.out", "df02.r", colnames(x))
x
#>   n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6 df02.r1 df02.r2
#> 1  1  2  3  4  5  6       5       2
#> 2  6  5  8  3  2  1       4       3
```

Comment: Wow, thanks @Simon Jackson, I ran a couple of tests, and the results are really impressive. Using loops I'm processing 1 row per second for each computer (df's are bigger than in my question). Your method can process around 14 ~ 16 rows per second for each computer. Now just some tweaks in code and done. Thanks again.

Comment: Great! If you find some improvements to this, please comment or edit my answer. I'd be interested to see (and make available to others).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea that should be more efficient, though it utilizes more memory:

It should be more convenient to store your "data.frame"s as matrices:

```
m1 = as.matrix(df1[, -1]); m2 = as.matrix(df2) 

m1
#     n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6
#[1,]  1  2  3  4  5  6
#[2,]  6  5  4  3  2  9
m2
#  m1 m2 m3 m4 m5
#1  1  2  3  4  5
#2  5  6  7  8  9
#3  1  3  2  5  8
```

Find all unique values:

```
lvs = union(m1, m2)
```

And tabulate in a sparse matrix (since each row does not contain duplicates and we do not duplicate counting anyway, we could use a "logical" matrix):

```
tab1 = sparseMatrix(i = row(m1), j = m1, x = TRUE) 
tab2 = sparseMatrix(i = row(m2), j = m2, x = TRUE)
```

And then:

```
tcrossprod(tab1, tab2)
#2 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#          
#[1,] 5 2 4
#[2,] 4 3 3
```

Where the intersections as `nrow(df1) * nrow(df2)` are stored.

Data are:

```
df1 = structure(list(id = 1:2, n1 = c(1L, 6L), n2 = c(2L, 5L), n3 = 3:4, 
n4 = c(4L, 3L), n5 = c(5L, 2L), n6 = c(6, 9)), .Names = c("id", 
"n1", "n2", "n3", "n4", "n5", "n6"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")


df2 = structure(list(m1 = c(1, 5, 1), m2 = c(2, 6, 3), m3 = c(3, 7, 
2), m4 = c(4, 8, 5), m5 = c(5, 9, 8)), .Names = c("m1", "m2", 
"m3", "m4", "m5"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```